# Jackson Json Serializer to Append Inner Properties

Tags: java, jackson, apple-push-notifications

I am working on parsing class to JSON for [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1). And so I have a `ApnsPayload` class and hoping to append the final JSON with the extra, optional and dynamic `acme` properties. It means I want to convert the following Jackson output...

```json
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "body",
            "title": "title"
        },
        "badge": 123,
        "category": "category"
    },
    "acme": {
        "1": "1",
        "value1": "value1"
    }
}
```

To this...

```json
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "body",
            "title": "title"
        },
        "badge": 123,
        "category": "category"
    },
    "acme-1": "1",
    "acme-value1": "value1"
}
```

I have successfully added a prefix `acme-` to those keys with `@JsonNaming()`, however I cannot move those properties by one level. Please help, thanks!

```java
@Value
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
// need a serializer to move up properties in Acme by one level
// @JsonSerialize(using = NewSerializer.class) 
public class ApnsPayload {

    private Aps aps;

    private Acme acme;

    @JsonNaming(AcmeNamingStrategy.class) // add prefix acme-
    public interface Acme {
    }

    @Value
    @Builder
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public static class Aps {

        private Alert alert;

        private Integer badge;

        private String sound;

        @JsonProperty("content-available")
        private Integer contentAvailable;

        private String category;

        @JsonProperty("thread-id")
        private String threadId;

        @Value
        @Builder
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        public static class Alert {

            private String title;
            private String body;

            @JsonProperty("title-loc-key")
            private String titleLocalizationKey;

            @JsonProperty("title-loc-args")
            private List<String> titleLocalizationArgs;

            @JsonProperty("action-loc-key")
            private String actionLocalizationKey;

            @JsonProperty("loc-key")
            private String localizationKey;

            @JsonProperty("loc-args")
            private List<String> localizationArgs;

            @JsonProperty("launch-image")
            private String launchImage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LOL, I found my answer 2 minutes after posting this question. All I need is the [Jackson Unwrapping Feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureUnwrapping), by adding `@JsonUnwrapped` to the property to be unwrapped.

```java
@JsonUnwrapped
private Acme acme;
```